# php script for getting a value in the database if it exist display some value

Tags: php

register has (id,firstname,lastname,email,username and password)

health_profile has (id,username,blood_group,age and weight)

contact_info has (username, phone, address, town).

I need to get the value of blood_group of the current user and and  display the contact_info all the other users in the database that can donate to them.

O-  can be donated  by O-

O+  can be donated by  O+ and O-

A-  can be donated by A- and O-

A+ can be donated by   A+ A- O+ O-

B- can be donated by B- and O-

B+ can be donated by B+ B- O- O+

AB- can be donated by AB- B- A- O-

AB+ can be donated by AB+ AB- B+ B- A+ A- O+ O-

Comment: It can be done, what did you try?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add some tables that include the relationships to be easier to agreggate the informations between the donors.

A graph database would be perfect to do that.
http://neo4j.com/